# How to burn ubuntu ISO to local drive in window and then boot from it?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, system-installation

I have ISO file of ubuntu 20 and I currently have windows 10 as the only OS installed. I created a bootable USB from ubuntu and, although I could boot into live ubuntu, I was not able to install it as it would always give me the error that the bootable device was corrupted. After searching a lot on web, I came to the conclusion that I cannot install it with the only USB I have so now I want to try something completely new. I want to create a separate 10 GB of partition, lets call it local drive (E:). Then I want to burn the iso onto this partition and then have this partition listed in the boot record such that if I boot from E, I should be able to install ubuntu. How can I do this? Is there any software for windows 10 that can be used to create a bootable partition from iso file and then how can I have that partition listed in boot menu?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20. There is a 20.04 and a 20.10

Comment: 10 gig is too small look at what is recommended. Also I do not think it may just be the USB the ISO may be bad.

Comment: @David yeah its ubuntu 20.04. And as for the size of drive than 10 gb is more than enough.

Comment: @user68186 thanks for the link. But that Answer does not mention how to add the partition to boot menu.

Comment: What boot menu? If you are asking about the Windows bootloader, then that is a Windows question, and off topic here. You can try change the boot order in the UEFI/BIOS and make the new partition the boot drive temporarily. Whatever way you boot from the Ubuntu "Live" partition, make sure it boots in the UEFI mode if Windows is installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: This is a windows problem. The fact you want to use an Ubuntu ISO is of no importance (the same would be possible using centos, freebsd, gentoo or even windows). "How can I do this?" whatever the answer it will not include any Linux command, It is all windows. imo dupe trumps off topic ;)

Comment: @David, I don't think Amir wants to install Ubuntu onto a 10GB partition. He just wants to copy his *.iso file there, and then boot directly from the iso file on disk into the Live environment. (Technically, a 3.5 GB partition will be enough for this, since `ubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso` is only 2.9 GB).

Comment: I agree with @Rinzwind's comment. There are instructions on this site on how to boot into a *.iso using the grub menu. However, you do not have grub installed until you install Linux. Therefore, you will need to modify the windows boot loader, and those instructions would not be on this site.